# JS - load animation for each element passed from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a webpage which does an AJAX call when someone searches for something. I want it so that when the results load in each result does a specific "loading animation" (like, each search result fades in separately - not the entire group of results fading in together).

How I currently have the JS is that all the objects get put in at the same time, but that only allows for me to style all of them at the same time.

Here's my code:

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Search',
  data: {
    'search_value': str
  },
  dataType: 'text',
})
.done(function(json) {
  var Search = JSON.parse(json), searchHTML = '', x;
  for (x in Search) {
    $('<span id="item'+x+"' class="search-item" style="display: none;">'+  Search[x] + '</span>').appendTo('#main');
    //this is to set the fade it
    //(the .css is there so it isn't accidentally forgotten about in the css)
    $('.search-item').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.search-item').fadeTo(500, 1);
  }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">

</div>
```

**I am trying to make it so that instead of all the html getting set at the end, it adds on to the last one, or something like that AND ALSO so that each one has an animation setting fire for it when it gets loaded into the html**

Thank you

**UPDATE**

The code has been updated with code from an answer below. still need the code to fire a new "load in animation" for each search response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use **[jquery `.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** function with `appendChild()` function, here's how will be your code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/Search',
  data: {
    'search_value': str
  },
  dataType: 'text',
})
.done(function(json) {
  var Search = JSON.parse(json), searchHTML = '', x;
  for (x in Search) {
    $('<span id="item'+x+"' class="search-item" style="display: none;">'+  Search[x] + '</span>').appendTo('#main').show('slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: wow this is an awesome answer! I am just making the show part work (it isn't working - little secret is the code I put in here is not the code I am using, so I have to make it work). Once I get it working I'll accept this, but otherwise, this is a great answer

Comment: okay so I have added it in, but it seems to be all doing it at the same time. i.e. I couldn't get `.show()` to work so I added a `.css()` on a new line (so it goes the line with `appendTo()`, then a `.css()` which makes the trainee go from `opacity: 0` to `opacity: 1`. (to make that less confusing I updated my Q above) It still seems to all load at the same time though... any ideas?

Comment: thank you. this works (I forgot the `display: none;` bit). I now need to work out further customizing it but the basic concept is there

Comment: @4lackof glad it helps ;).